# pass value to same php file

Tags: php, mysql, facebox

I have one php block under html for dropdown list which is under loop.Another php block is for popup window using facebox. Now How by clicking dropdown content pass value to second php block.

```
<?php


         $msql="select notification_id,applicant_id,notification_dis from app_notification where applicant_id=$app_id order by notification_id desc " ;
        $result_msql=$bd->query($msql);
        while($messagecount=$result_msql->fetch_assoc())

        {
        $not_id=    $messagecount['notification_id'];
        $comment=$messagecount['notification_dis'];


        ?>




            <div  class="comment_ui" >



        <a href="#info"  class='view_comments' rel='facebox' id="<?php echo $not_id; ?>"></br>   <?php echo "check1---$not_id".$comment."";?>
                </a>                  

            </div>
```

////Another is

```
      <?php



        echo $_POST['not_id'];  
       $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
      $mysql_user = "root";
      $mysql_password = "";
   $mysql_database = "test";
   $prefix = "";

        $bd = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user,           $mysql_password,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");


            echo "check2---$not_id";

            $msql_show="select  header_type,notification_main,notification_dis from app_notification where notification_id=$not_id";
            $show_msql=$bd->query($msql_show);

            while($message_show=$show_msql->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $header=$message_show['header_type'];
                $main=$message_show['notification_main'];


            $msql_multi="SELECT file_name FROM biz_logo WHERE    w_id=(SELECT w_id FROM post_job
            WHERE job_id=(SELECT job_id FROM job_notice WHERE 
            notice_id=(SELECT notice_id FROM app_notification where notification_id=$not_id)))";
            }
            $msql_multi=$bd->query($msql_multi);
            while($message_multi=$msql_multi->fetch_assoc())
            {

              $file_name=$message_multi['file_name'];



            }



            print "<center><h1>".$header."$not_id</h1></center>";
    print"<span style='margin-right:50em'><table> 
                 <p><t>".$file_name."</t></p><tr><td>".$main."</td>
    </tr> <tr><td></td></tr></table><span> ";              
            ?>





        <?php }?>
```

Comment: I want use not_id when click

Comment: You will have to pass value to second block (change it to function) via ajax or you will have to submit the page on click.

Comment: '$(".view_comments").click(function() 
{
 

var ID = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "notifications.php",
data: "not_id="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(data){
alert("working");
}
});

return false;
});'

Comment: Imposible. PHP is server side, and the click is client site. When someone clicks on your page no php code is on his client site, only HTML or JavaScript. You can sent Data to your server with a Formular, or you can use Javascript(AJAX).

Comment: this is my javascript  function... but in the second block not recognize 'not_id' index

Answer (score 0):

in php manually you can use sessions or if you need

```
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";


<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>
```

or if you need use html you can use inputbox and post get method

Comment: when I click content on dropdown the id of that content should be sent on second block

The id I can get from database.. Here shows notification_id

Comment: I understand that the second block is for showing content in popup using facebox. If that is the case you can just create a popup.php and pass variable as query string. Like popup.php? not_id=1 (whatever). See facebox options to do this. Obviously, your second block of code should be in popup.php.

Comment: so the code would be      <a href="popup.php?not_id=<your-notification-id>" rel="facebox">notification</a>